# How to capture division in SQL query

Tags: python, regex

I want to capture division whenever they occur in sql query.

so I suppose regex should work

```
(s+)\/(s+)
```

Test is

```
a/b = b/d and c/e is not equal to b/e
```

I used it at http://regexr.com/ but it seems to return no result.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you also need to account for whitespace before and/or after the division operator? If yes, then it's not too difficult to modify from falsetru's answer as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

- Use `\S` to match non-space, not `\s`. Seems you missed backslash.
- You don't need to escape `/` in Python regular expression.

---

```
>>> re.findall(r'(\S+)/(\S+)', 'a/b = b/d and c/e is not equal to b/e')
[('a', 'b'), ('b', 'd'), ('c', 'e'), ('b', 'e')]
```